# Cards won't work with paypal sandbox testing

Tags: paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to create a simple subscription payment on sandbox PayPal.
I have a business account on sandbox, with which I have created a subscription plan.
Furthermore, I have a test user on sandbox with a credit card generated here: https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/sandbox/card-testing/

Everything works fine but when I get to the payment confirmation I get this message: "Sorry, cannot use your chosen payment method to set up subscription item. Please try other payment method"

I tried using other cards or creating another test user but I always get this same error.

I've also posted the question in the paypal community but didn't get any response: https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Sandbox-Environment/Subscriptions-payment-declined-because-test-card-not-working/m-p/3023752

---

Second problem: When i make a simple payment it works fine, but when I try the pay in 4, it tells me to setup a card (even though I already have a card setuped) and when I try to resetup it on the payment modal I get the error : "We cannot process your request at this time. Try again later."

I thought maybe if I add credit to my test account I can bypass this. But when I go to the page to add credit (https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/myaccount/money/addmoney/topup) it's blank and there are errors in the console.
So I tried to send money to me test account from another account and it doesn't work either...

I was wondering is there like an option or something I have to activate or disable in the settings so my test will work, or is the PayPal sandbox environment just bugged ?

If you need anymore informations or details don't hesitate to ask, I'm not sure if my explaining was clear.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new sandbox personal account at https://developer.paypal.com/dashboard/accounts .  Use that account to test the subscription.
2. The result of Pay in 4 payments is a PayPal payment. You can already test PayPal payments *without* Pay in 4 as a funding source. So, do not test Pay in 4 in sandbox. There is no reason to.

Comment: 1. Created a new sandbox account, but still the same problem for the subscription.
2. So i can treat a pay in 4 response the same as a simple payment ? But could this be problematic for billing ? (Like a simple payment will just return an amount, but pay in 4 needs to have 4 amount with dates)

Comment: Maybe there's something wrong with your subscription, but those details aren't in the question. Pay in 4 results in a single lump sum paid to the receiver account. For integration purposes, it is the same as any other PayPal payment.

Comment: Hum i will try again creating subscriptions. Thanks for the info for the pay in 4, it's good to know